# Unable to find record from outer join

Tags: apache-pig

I have two relations whose schema and data is as below:

latest_extract

```
ticket_num,employee_id,assigned_to,team,assigned_date
1234567,1122525,michael,printer,2019-01-03
1234569,1122536,julie,printer,2019-01-03
1234571,1122538,priscila,printer,2019-01-03
1234572,1122539,susan,scanner,2019-01-03
1234573,1122540,walter,network,2019-01-03
```

previous_extract

```
ticket_num,employee_id,assigned_to,team,assigned_date
1234567,1122525,michael,printer,2019-01-02
1234568,1122525,michale,printer,2019-01-02
1234569,1122536,julie,printer,2019-01-02
1234570,1122537,john,scanner,2019-01-02
1234574.1122541,hudson,windows,2019-01-02
```

```
join_latest_previous = JOIN previous_extract BY (ticket_num,employee_id) FULL OUTER, latest_extract BY (ticket_num,employee_id);

latest_extract::ticket_num,latest_extract::employee_id,latest_extract::assigned_to,latest_extract::team,latest_extract::assigned_date,
previous_extract::ticket_num,previous_extract::employee_id,previous_extract::assigned_to,previous_extract::team,previous_extract::assigned_date;
1234567,1122525,michael,printer,2019-01-03,1234567,1122525,michael,printer,2019-01-02
,,,,,1234568,1122525,michale,printer,2019-01-02
1234569,1122536,julie,printer,2019-01-03,1234569,1122536,julie,printer,2019-01-02
1234571,1122538,priscila,printer,2019-01-03,,,,,
1234572,1122539,susan,scanner,2019-01-03,,,,,
,,,,,1234570,1122537,john,scanner,2019-01-02
,,,,,1234573,1122540,walter,network,2019-01-03
1234574.1122541,hudson,windows,2019-01-02,,,,,,
```

I need to do below:
if there is single emp in team and record of employee does not exist in previous extract but in latest then flag is 1,
else if there is single emp in team and record of employee does not exist in latest extract but in previous then flag is 2,
else if there are multiple emp in team and record of employee does not exist in previous extract but in latest then flag is 3,
else if there are multiple emp in team and record of employee does not exist in latest extract but in previous then flag is 4,
else it would be 5.

```
diff_latest_previous = FOREACH join_latest_previous GENERATE 
((((previous_extract::ticket_num IS NULL) AND (latest_extract::ticket_num IS NOT NULL))OR (previous_extract::ticket_num !=latest_extract::ticket_num))?1:
(((previous_extract::ticket_num IS NOT NULL) AND (latest_extract::ticket_num IS NULL))OR (previous_extract::ticket_num !=latest_extract::ticket_num))?2:
3) AS flag, latest_extract::ticket_num AS l_ticket_num,latest_extract::employee_id AS l_employee_id,latest_extract::assigned_to AS l_assigned_to,latest_extract::team AS l_team,latest_extract::assigned_date AS l_assigned_date,previous_extract::ticket_num AS p_ticket_num,previous_extract::employee_id AS p_employee_id,previous_extract::assigned_to AS p_assigned_to,previous_extract::team AS p_team,previous_extract::assigned_date AS p_assigned_date;

flag,ticket_num,employee_id,assigned_to,team,assigned_date
5,1234567,1122525,michael,printer,2019-01-03,1234567,1122525,michael,printer,2019-01-02
1,,,,,1234568,1122525,michale,printer,2019-01-02
5,1234569,1122536,julie,printer,2019-01-03,1234569,1122536,julie,printer,2019-01-02
2,1234571,1122538,priscila,printer,2019-01-03,,,,,
2,1234572,1122539,susan,scanner,2019-01-03,,,,,
1,,,,1234570,1122537,john,scanner,2019-01-02
1,,,,,,1234573,1122540,walter,network,2019-01-03
2,1234574.1122541,hudson,windows,2019-01-02,,,,,,
```

Here, I am unable to get the value of 3 and 4.

Please help me to find a way for that.

Comment: The script you pasted only has flag 1,2 and 3 but not 4 & 5 ?

Comment: The reason behind it is that I am unable to design the logic for it. Please help to sort it out.